# Get IPv4Address of user in ASP.NET with VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ip

I want to get the IPv4Address but this code return some other IP address that is always the same. How can I get the Users IP address?

```
Private Function GetIPv4Address() As String

        GetIPv4Address = String.Empty
        Dim strHostName As String = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()
        Dim iphe As System.Net.IPHostEntry = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(strHostName)

        For Each ipheal As System.Net.IPAddress In iphe.AddressList
            If ipheal.AddressFamily = System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork Then
                GetIPv4Address = ipheal.ToString()
            End If
        Next

        lblIP.Text = GetIPv4Address

    End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being my solution.

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">

<script type="application/javascript">

    var myip;
    function ip_callback(o) 
    {
        myip = o.host;
    }

    function Theval() 
    {
        document.getElementById('lblIP').innerText = myip
    }

</script>

<script type="application/javascript" src="https://smart-ip.net/geoip-json?callback=ip_callback"></script>

<title></title>

</head>

<body onload="Theval()">

    <form id="form1" runat="server">

             <asp:Label ID="lblIP" runat="server" Text="lblIP">aaa</asp:Label>

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Function GetExternalIp() As String
    Try
        Dim externalIP As String =New WebClient().DownloadString("http://checkip.dyndns.org/")
        externalIP = (New Regex("\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}")) _
                     .Matches(externalIP)(0).ToString()
        Return externalIP
    Catch
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```

Edit:

You never mentioned that this was part of a web site, although I see that it is tagged as ASP .NET now.  That makes a HUGE difference.  What you are seeing is the IP address of the server that your web site is running on.  Therefore it is the same for every visitor.  If you want the IPs of individual visitors, then you will need to do it on the client-side using `JavaScript`.  VB (and ASP) .NET only runs on the server side.

This might not be the prettiest solution, but it should work:

```
function getIp()
{
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
    {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else 
    {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php",false);    
    xmlhttp.send();   
    var hostIpInfo = xmlhttp.responseText.split("\n");

    for (i=0; hostIpInfo.length >= i; i++) 
    {
        ipAddress = hostIpInfo[i].split(":");
        if ( ipAddress[0] == "IP" ) 
        {
            return ipAddress[1];
        }
    }
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/74VPv/) is a fiddle with the above code

Comment: When I go to this url http://checkip.dyndns.org directly the IP is different from the code, why?

Comment: What does it come up as in the code?  Also, are you behind a proxy?

Comment: I have no idea about the proxy, its just showing a different address. Only the first 2 numbers in the IP is the same.

Comment: Even when I do IPCONFIG on my local PC it shows a different IP than from the url or any other webites that shows your IP

Comment: @Etienne Does it show an IP that starts with `192.168` or `10.0`?  If so, that is your "private IP" (the IP that is internal to your network).  The various websites show your "public IP", which is the IP  that is exposed to the Internet.

Comment: Nope, starts with 41, I want the IP that is exposed to the internet like on the website http://www.ipchicken.com

Comment: And that IP is different than what `checkip.dyndns.org` shows?  How about `whatismyip.com`?

Comment: These 2 websites you send me now shows me the same IP, but when I run the code the IP generated is different.

Comment: It's returning the same IP address for all my users on my site.

Comment: Cool thanks! Do you have some JavaScript for me that will do it?

Comment: Thanks, I posted my own answer, please see what I did, I appreciate your assistance! 1 Up for that!